# How to determine what a site is using for specific UI effects?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, css-transitions, jquery-hover

I am redesigning a site based on another one of our company site's designs/UI

The web developer that is responsible for the website I am supposed to be modeling my redesign after is on vacation for the next week, but I wanted to use one of his UI effects.

I can't seem to figure out what he's using for a hover fade effect, which makes me think he's not using CSS3, but some jQuery library.

EDIT: I have used firebug to try and figure out what they are doing without success.

[Here](http://www.iaea.org/) is what I'm looking at. Its the fade effect used on a couple of elements in the right sidebar. The class is `fadehover`.

Help to diagnose this specific issue is appreciated, but I would really like to know how I myself can figure similar issues out in the future.

Comment: Use http://getfirebug.com/ to find that.

Comment: I have been using firebug for a couple years now, but I can't seem to figure out what they're doing on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in main.js (line 223) I found this which is responsible for the hovers:

```
$("img.img-a").hover(
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 400);
},
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 800);
});
```

Within the `fadehover` div's, there are images with the classes `img-a` and `img-b`. When the cursor hovers over `img-a`, it fades out that image. So I assume `img-b` is put behind `img-a` using CSS.

**This is how I did it:**

I used Google Chrome, went to the tab `resources` and simply searched (ctrl + F / cmd + F) for the `fadehover` class. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything but a bit of CSS and HTML so I picked a class of one of the images within that div which had this as result, bingo!

There are other ways to find out. If you inspect that element and hover with your mouse you might see your DOM changing. If your DOM changes you know it's done by javascript. Whether it's jQuery, prototype or another framework is another story.

If the DOM doesn't change, you can be sure a CSS transition is used. Unless Flash, SVG or the HTML5 canvas element is used ;)

Comment: Excellent, but how did you go about finding that? What did you search for? What did you use? I am really good at figuring out CSS effects with firebug, but when its jQuery I can't figure out how to find what its doing.

Comment: Wow awesome, thanks so much. Do you know if there is a way to do the same thing in firefox (firebug)?

Comment: In firebug you have multiple tabs for every language. HTML, CSS and Script. So first you have to know if you should look in the CSS or Script tab. If you use the script tab, you have to enable it first by clicking on the arrow and click `enable`. Then you have to reload the page, which loads all scripts in that tab. Then, you can search for whatever you are looking for. That's why I prefer Chrome, because I can search all files instantly. I prefer Chrome for debugging anyway.